# Form Builder module not working in Drupal 7

Tags: forms, 7

Can someone confirm if [Form Builder module](http://drupal.org/project/form_builder) is working on your end. I review the `.module` and seems like the paths are still using Drupal 6 format.

Comment: Which part of the module file do you mean? `hook_menu()` didn't change much (if at all) in Drupal 7 so it's right that you don't see any difference there. The module has a stable release so there's no immediate reason it wouldn't work. Have you actually tried it and found errors?

Comment: After installation I can't see the links in the admin menu? There is no permission to enable also. Weird coz no error upon installation.

Comment: Try clearing the caches, that should get the links into the admin menu. Try going to "admin/build/form-builder/add" to see if it's installed ok. Form builder doesn't implement any permissions so that's why they're not there :)

Comment: Tried to access this path `admin/build/form-builder/add` but it gives me access denied:
`Access denied
You are not authorized to access this page.`

Comment: I already flush the cache in the CMS and also run `drush cc all`

Comment: Sorry my bad, I get what you mean now. The paths themselves (admin/build/*) look like Drupal 6 paths. Try enabling the included examples module then going to "/form-builder-example", that works for me at least

Comment: Yeah that works Clive....

Comment: This module is really great but sad that it has a major problem in using it

Comment: So what was the solution for this? I can see `/form-builder-example` but that is fairly useless without being able to use the rest of it!

Comment: Did any one of you found the solution? the module is installed and i am unable to find where to start from. Is the form-builder-example is the only gate way to get through ! Please assist me. Does this module capable of maintaining records in database.I dint find the submit button !

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to activate it. If you read well the requirements to install formbuilder you will find one of the options is to install Options Element. Please refer to this link http://drupal.org/project/form_builder and see the requirements.